# Skip every Nth row in CSV parser

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, opencsv

I am using opencsv parser. In my csv file there can be about 100,000 rows. It takes too much time to read them. How can I skip and read every Nth row (each 30th row for example)?

```kotlin
private suspend fun readCSVRides(folder: String): MutableList<RideDataCsv>? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

    val path = getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.path + "/" + folder + "/" + "measurements.csv"

    var segments: MutableList<RideDataCsv>? = null

    var fileReader: BufferedReader? = null
    val csvToBean: CsvToBean<RideDataCsv>?

    try {
        fileReader = BufferedReader(FileReader(path))
        csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder<RideDataCsv>(fileReader)
            .withType(RideDataCsv::class.java)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
            .build()

        segments = csvToBean.parse()
       
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Reading CSV Error!")
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            fileReader!!.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("Closing fileReader/csvParser Error!")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    segments
}
```

Comment: Why not to write a parser and to write what you want? CSV, it's just ordinary file?

Comment: you can use `uniVocity CSV parser` which is faster than `opencsv` you can see the benchmark [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison#jdk-9).

Comment: @StanislavBatura Handling of commas inside of quoted strings can be tricky to implement correctly and efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a `Reader` that skips every nth line in the input and wrap your `fileReader` like so:

```kotlin
fileReader = SkipReader(BufferedReader(FileReader(path)), skipEvery = 30)
```

Below is an example of how it could be implemented:

```kotlin
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.StringReader
import java.io.Reader

class SkipReader(
    private val input: Reader,
    private val skipEvery: Int
) : Reader(input) {

    private var linesToSkip = skipEvery - 1
    private var isSkipping = false
    
    override fun read(cbuf: CharArray, offset: Int, len: Int): Int {
        var bytesRead = 0
        while (bytesRead < len) {
            val value = input.read()
            if (value == -1) {
                break
            }
            val c = value.toChar()
            if (c == '\n') {
                if (linesToSkip == 0) {
                    linesToSkip = skipEvery - 1
                    isSkipping = false
                } else {
                    isSkipping = true
                }
                if (isSkipping) {
                    linesToSkip--
                }
            }
            if (!isSkipping) {
                cbuf[offset + bytesRead] = c
                bytesRead++
            }
        }
        return if (bytesRead > 0) bytesRead else -1
    }
    
    override fun close() {
        input.close()
    }
}
```

It may be a good idea to improve performance by overriding other methods, but not only `read` and `close`, as they are the only required to be overridden. Also reading several characters at once instead of reading them one-by-one in `input.read()` may also help, however it could be already be handled well by BufferedReader.

Testing on a few lines:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val csvText = 
        """
            Line 1
            Line 2
            Line 3
            Line 4
            Line 5
            Line 6
            Line 7
        """.trimIndent()
    val reader = SkipReader(BufferedReader(StringReader(csvText)), skipEvery = 2)
    for (line in reader.readLines()) {
        println(line)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 5
Line 7
```